# jqGrid + multiselect: duplicate selection if I pre-select rows on loading

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am still struggling to understand how **jqGrid** works with **multiselect**.
When I thought I knew everything about it, again another problem.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/bCHUW/1/) you can find an example of what's happening.

I want to preselect some rows in a multiselect grid.
If you click the button it will tell you that you have 13 rows selected. Very good.
Now, if you check all the rows using the "**SelectAll**" button you'll find out that the rows selected are 40.
The problem is the grid only has 29 rows :-s
It's like it keeps the previous selection and adds the new rows selected.
Any help would be really really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code demonstrate the bug in jqGrid 3.8.2. jqGrid must reset `selarrrow` to empty array `[]`:

```
ts.p.selarrrow = [];
```

before the filling ids of all selected rows. I verified that **the bug is already fixed** in the code of jqGrid on the github.com: see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2047). So if you use developer version of jqGrid you can just add in the code of jqGrid 3.8.2 the line. Alternative you can get the last (can be not so good tested code) from the [github.com](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid) or wait for the next release of jqGrid. :-)

Comment: I was waiting for you, Oleg ;-) Thanks for your help...once again. Where can I find the developer version? Plus, if I update that one how can I compact everything in one single file?

Comment: Oleg,I've managed to change it in my file (jquery.jqGrid.min.js). The update for the 3.8.2 version is a.p.selarrrow = [];

Comment: @LeftyX: The developer version (uncompressed version) you find in the `src` directory of [the jqGrid download](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6). [Here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_to_install#development_installation) you can find more information about the usage of the developer version.

Comment: @Lefty, where did you changed in (jquery.jqGrid.min.js) file ?. Bcoz i'm still facing the same issue after i made the changes.

Comment: @SundarG: You should just don't use the retro version 3.8.2. I recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5 instead. You can load jqGrid files directly from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and [the code example](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code).